# fontawesome5 (pro) and XeLaTeX

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontawesome

I am trying to use `fontawesome5` with the pro option, hence also with XeLaTeX, and it is a little strange. Consider the following minimal example

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xunicode,fontspec,xltxtra,refcount,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage[pro]{fontawesome5}%
\faStyle{light}
\begin{document}
  \faIcon{globe}
\end{document}
```

It takes quite a while to run (MacOS TeXlive 2018), this takes even far longer with more icons and produces an error (for more icons more errors) like

```
kpathsea:make_tex: Invalid filename `FontAwesome5ProSolid:script=latn;', contains ':'

Latex Error: /usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontawesome5/fontawesome5-utex-helper.sty:59 Font TU/fontawesomepro/solid/n/10.95=FontAwesome5ProSolid:script=latn; at 10.95pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or installed font not found.


relax

l.59 ...ze_font:nn{\c__fontawesome_kind_tl}{solid}
```

and sometimes (not completely reproducible/not appearing every time)

```
!

! The font "FontAwesome" cannot be found.

!

! See the fontspec documentation for further information.

!

! For immediate help type H .

!...............................................

l.45 \newfontfamily{\FA}{FontAwesome}
```

But though the compilation then takes quite a wile (for my larger file with 6 icons 5 minutes, the small one above maybe 30 seconds) – a PDF is created that looks fine and as expected.

What's happening there? For me it looks like, though running XeLaTeX it's trying some pdflatex-fun?

Comment: Do you have the pro-Version of the fonts installed? They are not free. If not, then do not use the pro oprion

Comment: I am Kickstarter Backer and yes they are installed. To be precise, it seems to be really the `pro` option being a problem, since the above MWE works with `\usepackage{fontawesome5}` and `\faStyle{regular}`

Comment: sure, then the fonts are used  which are part of the TeX system  and installed by the package manager. In which directory are your pro fonts installed?

Comment: In the system – since XeLaTeX takes the font from the system then. Actually, I _only_ have the pro font installed, did not follow the installation instructions for the free ones (in the `fontawesome5` pdf). What surprises me the most is, that it still works and even takes the `light` style.

Comment: In my PDF it uses `FontAwesome5FreeSolid`, which are installed by the package itself! See https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/fontawesome5/opentype

Comment: Interestingly setting the style to `light` seems (?) to use the even lighter than regular icons on my side. How can I check for the font in the PDF? So then maybe – I need to find the way to install the pro fonts somewhere besides the free ones? The manual just states “uses XeLaTeX” and since that works for my other fonts directly with the system – I am already stunned for 3 hours that it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem consisted of two parts. After I reinstalled FontAwesome Pro, both errors for the MWE were gone, but the first remained for my starting point, the [`komacv`](https://ctan.org/pkg/komacv).

With careful inspection I found, that `komacv` is loading `fontawesome` already, commenting that out makes my file (loading `fontawesome5` myself) compile. I will contact the author of `komacv`.